# Calculating molecular formulas of a combustion reaction

Tags: stoichiometry

### The Question

In an experiment, 10 cm$^3$
of an organic compound in the gaseous state was sparked with an excess of oxygen. 20 cm$^3$
of
carbon dioxide and 5 cm$^3$
of nitrogen were obtained among
the products. All gas volumes were measured at the same
temperature and pressure. What are the possible molecular
formulas that would fit these data?

### My Attempt

Since there is one volume of $\ce{N2}$ produced from 2 volumes of the organic compound, there must be one $\ce{N}$ atom in the compound. Also, 4 volumes of $\ce{CO2}$ is formed from 2 volumes of the organic compound and thus the number of carbon atoms must be 2. It follows that the compound must be $\ce{C_{2}H_{x}N}$. Therefore the compound must be $\ce{C_{2}H_{7}N}$, $\ce{C_{2}H_{5}N}$, or $\ce{C_{2}H_{3}N}$.

The answer key states that the only compounds which satisfy the conditions are $\ce{C_{2}H_{7}N}$ and $\ce{C_{2}H_{3}N}$.

Why isn't $\ce{C_{2}H_{5}N}$ a valid solution, given that the balanced chemical reaction of it reacting with oxygen satisfies all the conditions?

Comment: You are right. I don't see why $\ce{C2H5N}$ cannot be accepted.

Comment: Ohk thanks I asked cause all the answers available online also gave the same answers. Thanks!